# Design Pattern for varying fields

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am coding a directory parser utility, which scans different directories for different type of files.

Now a straightforward implementation urges me to do the following. 
Have a list of directories to parse, loop over them and pass it to a method that actually does the file I/O and other logic and returns the result.

```
List<Dir> dirList;
//loop over the list and call parseDirecotry()
parseDirectory(Dir dirToParse){
 //do file io
 if (filename.matches("pattern"){
 //proceed)
 }
}
```

Each directory that's scanned requires me to filter out certain files. So now
for certails dir the match pattern will vary, now either I could keep adding the match pattern based on the type of directory in if else logic. 
Or 
I could take the pattern out make of it a part of the Dir object, make it abstract, have specific directory implementations hold the specific match pattern.

This way I don't have to touch the parseDirectory method every time I have a new directory to scan.

Question is: is there some design pattern that I could possible leverage here? What are you views about the above program to interface way and do you think if it would make sense to move the parseDirectory() method up to the abstract directory class as well?

Comment: does each directory contains different file formats. Ex : Dir 1 contains : .doc, .xls etc , Dir 2 : .doc,.pdf,.jpg etc ?

Comment: @saury: more likely a different nomenclature for filenames than extensions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I will propose my solution

1) Create an interface called IFileProcessor having method processFile
2) Create singleton classes specific to document types implementing IFileProcessor. So the classes will be DocFileProcessor, XLSFileProcessor etc and each class will have its own specific implementation of processFile API.
3)Create a factory class say FileProcessorFactory. It should have an API called `IFileProcessor getFileProcessor(String fileTypeExtension)` . This API will take file extension as input and return the DocFileProcessor, XLSFileProcessor etc for input doc, xls etc.
4) In your loop call  getFileProcessor of  FileProcessorFactory giving it input. Now call processFile on returned instance.

Having this design decouples the logic of if-else to Factor allowing you logic to remain independent of the file types.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and wth a few changes i probably could work with this disign. e.g. have a default implemantaion for processFile() in FileProcesser abstract class, wrap dir and RegexFileFilter in this as well (as suggested by @John B), have specific implementaions specify the RegexFileFilter.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think having a file name search pattern as part of the `Dir` is a good design. However, a `FileSearch` object that encapsulates the `Dir` and `Pattern` might be a nice design.

Another thing to think about is that Apache Commons `FileUtils` provides this kind of functionality in the `listFiles` method using `IOFileFilter` instances such as `RegexFileFilter`. You could create a class that wraps an `IOFileFilter` for the `Dir` and a `RegexFileFilter` for the file name.

Comment: +1 on the `FileUtils` [listFiles()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter,%20org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.IOFileFilter%29) approach. They've solved the problem, and their solution is battle-tested. Leverage it and move on :-)

Comment: @John B: This makes sense, IOFileFilter takes an extra if condition away and if I couple it with Saury's suggestion a factory would decide which implementation to instantiate, the implemntation would know RegexFileFilter to use.

Answer (score 0):

Few points:

- I wont suggest to have the pattern as the part of Directory.
- The Patterns should be part of the object which implement some interface like : IParser
  which has a method which takes a directory object and do that parsing as required.
- You can have different IParser implementations for extension, file length etc.